# Adjusting integer array based on string in C

Tags: c, arrays, atoi

array should have the first 0 in each pair changed to the next number in string inputlist.

**Code**:

```
{
    int array[8][8][2]= {{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}},
                {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}},
                {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}},
                {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}},
                {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}},
                {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}},
                {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}},
                {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}};
    size_t i,j,p;
    char duck;
    char inputList[66] = "01111011001111110110010110010100001011011000101111111000110100001";

    i=0;
    j=0;

    for(p=0;p<strlen(inputList);p++){
        if(i==7){
            i=0;
        }
        if(j==7){
            j=0;
        }
        duck=inputList[p];
        array[i][j][0]=atoi(duck);
        i+=1;
        j+=1;
    }



        return 0;




}
```

returns errors to do with atoi. What's going on?

**Error**:

> passing argument 1 of ‘atoi’ makes pointer from integer without a cast

I'm a little confused as to what it means by cast. I feel I've muddled it up trying to compensate.

Comment: `inputList[p]`is a char, `atoi()` expects a string aka `char*`.

Comment: Also: 1) fix formatting 2) add error handling: `i`and `j` should never exceed `7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use `atoi` to parse single-digit numbers. However, since `atoi` expects a C string and takes a `const char*`, you cannot pass it a plain char. You need to pass it a properly terminated C string.
Try this:
`array[i][j][0]= duck-'0';`

Comment: OK, I'm not sure what's going on but with this in my code it only edits my array partially it seems. I'll add my reasoning to my initial question.

Comment: forget it, I need two loops, I'll remove it. Thanks you've helped me solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
array[i][j][0] = duck - '0';
```

It converts a digit in `char duck` into an integer by using ASCII code manipulations.

Comment: nm got it. should use '

Comment: @Jack It should be `single quote` and not `tilda`